# natbib: modifying citation style for particular source type, while others remain default

Tags: punctuation, natbib

I'm using `natbib` and would like to modify the punctuation style for one particular type of source (classical texts), while punctuation for remaining sources should remain at their default settings.

In particular, I would like to cite ancient texts without author names and without commas: e.g. Aristotle's Politics, section 123, would be referred to in-text like this:

> blablabla (Politics 123)

whereas other sources should be referred to in-text in the default manner, i.e. as author-year, with a comma between year and page:

> yadayayaya (Smith 1992, 33).

So far I'm using `\defcitealias` and `\citepalias`, which works fine except for the punctuation:

```
\defcitealias{Aristotle1992}{\textit{Politics}}  
\citepalias[123]{Aristotle1992}
```

results in

> (Politics, 123)

=> I would like to get rid of the comma here, while still keeping the comma for the other references.

Is there any way of achieving this from within the `natbib` package (if at all possible, I'd rather not switch to e.g. `biblatex`)...? I'd be immensely grateful for any help.

---

Here's some example code (hope this classifies as a workable example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Aristotle1992,
  title = {The Politics},
  publisher = {London: Penguin},
  year = {1992},
  author = {Aristotle}
    }

@BOOK{Smith2003,
  title = {Blalala},
  publisher = {London: Penguin},
  year = {2003},
  author = {Smith, John}
    }
\end{filecontents}  
\usepackage{natbib}  
\begin{document}  

\defcitealias{Aristotle1992}{\textit{Politics}}    

This is as close as I get to what I want, but I would like to get rid of the comma:  

\citepalias[123a]{Aristotle1992}  

Other sources should be referred to in the usual way though (author date, page):  

\citep[p.~222]{Smith2003}  

\bibliographystyle{chicago}    
\bibliography{\jobname}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be handy to have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) here: while the question is pretty clear, it's almost always best to have something others can compile in the question as it makes it more likely you'll get a good answer.

Comment: Try to put in your preamble:
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \makeatletter
    \preto\citepalias{\renewcommand\NAT@cmt{\space}}{}{}
    \makeatother

Comment: @user25177 I've formatted your MWE so it's marked up as code, and have also slightly modified it so the `.bib` file is auto-generated from the `.tex` file.

Comment: @deimi Looks good: could you make that an answer?

Comment: @joseph: thanks a lot and sorry for my clumsy formatting/bib-file usage..

Comment: @deimi: thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately I don't seem to get it work, my alias still has the comma...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code just after `usepackage{natbib}`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\save@NAT@cmt\NAT@cmt % saving comma 
\def\restore@NAT@cmt{\global\let\NAT@cmt\save@NAT@cmt} % restoring comma
\def\fix@NAT@cmt{\def\NAT@cmt{\space\restore@NAT@cmt}} % fix for citepalias
\preto\citepalias{\fix@NAT@cmt}{}{}  % patching citepalias
\makeatother
```

The output: 
[image]

Comment: Excellent, many many thanks! Precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `classics` package too:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{classics}
\newclassic{Aristotle}{#1|\textit{#1}|#1}

\begin{document}

\Aristotle [Politics]{1260}[a]

\Aristotle [Politics]{1260}[a][2]

\Aristotle*[Politics]{1260}[a][2]{1261}[b][3]

\end{document}
```

And this is how to use `classics` in conjunction with `biblatex`, `biblatex-chicago`, or `natbib` (and deimi's answer): you need to enclose `\Aristotle` in braces.

```
\cite[{\Aristotle{1260}[a][2]}]{Aristotle1992}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful! Due to some other issues, I have actually now migrated from natbib to biblatex-chicago (even though I was not so keen on that in my earlier post), so now I've ended up using entrysubtype={classical} in my bibfile, which works quite well too.

Comment: `\Aristotle{1260}[a][2]` just prints `1260a2` in a user-defined format (column `a` or `b` in italics). You may use `classics` with `biblatex-chicago` as well: `\parencite[{\Aristotle{1260}[a][2]}]{Aristotle1992}`