# add ancient text citation export endnote to .bib

Tags: citing, natbib, endnotes

I am trying to cite classical sources / ancient texts in the original and I would like to create a new entry for it in my bibtex export from endnote. I use natbib. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% begin preamble 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}

subsubsection*{Introduction}

In the article `Seafaring as social action' by Helen Farr \citep{RN59}.

\bibliography{exam}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\end{document}
```

where my .bib

```
@ancienttext{RN59,
   author = {Lucan},
   title = {Pharsalia},
   volume = {2},
   number = {2 Number},
   address = {Turnhout},
   publisher = {Brepols Publishers},
   year = {2010},
}
```

[image]

and the bib entry is the following

[image]

when it should present with this information in this format
[image]

APA (6th ed.)

Lucan, ., & In Duff, J. D. (1962). Lucan: The civil war, books I-X (Pharsalia). Cambridge, Mass: Harvard University Press.

Chicago (Author-Date, 15th ed.)

Lucan, and J. D. Duff. 1962. Lucan: The civil war, books I-X (Pharsalia). Cambridge, Mass: Harvard University Press.

Harvard (18th ed.)

LUCAN, & DUFF, J. D. (1962). Lucan: The civil war, books I-X (Pharsalia). Cambridge, Mass, Harvard University Press.

MLA (7th ed.)

Lucan, , and J D. Duff. Lucan: The Civil War, Books I-X (pharsalia). Cambridge, Mass: Harvard University Press, 1962. Print.

Turabian (6th ed.)

Lucan, and J. D. Duff. Lucan: The civil war, books I-X (Pharsalia). Cambridge, Mass: Harvard University Press, 1962.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. How do you do ancient texts. Provide an MWE (from `\documentclass... to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. Help us to help you.

Comment: I updated my question field. If possible, to have a place for a translator and editor in the bibliogrpahy and the in text citation to display only the original author and the line numbers ( i know how to add line numbers but i have only seen ways to delete the comma post hoc with edited code in the file instead of fixing the bibtex export from endnote. I feel like fixing the export / adding a new type of citation would be easier so it would just be correct every time ...but i am not the expert

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95823/natbib-modifying-citation-style-for-particular-source-type-while-others-remain

here is the example I found for editing code within the document

Comment: That is not an MWE. How do you expect us to compile something that ends with `\usepackage{natbib}`?

Comment: I edited it. But my question isn’t about my tex document but rather how to create a new citation type in endnote that converts correctly to a .bib file that is compatible with natbib. Not sure how my actual document/mwe will help with that

Comment: It is possible, but fairly painful, to invent a new entry type like `@ancienttext` for a BibTeX style that does not know it yet. (You would have to add a function for the new entry type to the `.bst` file. BibTeX's `.bst` use a fairly unusual programming language by today's standard.) In this case you chances of getting sensible output are much higher if you just use the standard `@book` entry type.

Comment: @moewe how would I do this? it is not just for ancient text, I would like to create other entry types for websites, newspapers, etc. I feel this will be the least painful path... unless you see another way?